Sagetex: issue with \sagestr
I’m encountering an issue with \sagestr{} while using TeXstudio. Although the PDF compilation completes successfully, I still receive an error message related to \sagestr{}.
To illustrate the problem, here is a minimal working example along with the error it generates:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}

% Generación de tabla de valores

\begin{sagesilent}
def tabla_valores(fun, xi):
    n = len(xi)
    # Aquí almacenamos la coordenada y
    yi = []
    for k in range(n):
        yi.append(fun.subs(x=xi[k]))
    # Comienza el codigo latex
    s = [r'\begin{center}$\displaystyle f(x)='+r'{0}$'.format(latex(fun))+r'\end{center}']
    # Primera linea de la tabla
    s.append(r'\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{r|r}$x$&$y$\\ \hline')
    # Bucle para generar los puntos de la tabla
    for k in range(n):
        s.append(r'${0}$&{1}$\\'.format(latex(xi[k]),latex(yi[k])))
    # Cerramos la tabla de valores
    s.append(r'\end{tabular}\end{center}')
    return ''.join(s)
\end{sagesilent}

\sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2,[-2,1])}

\end{document}

Error:
document.tex: error: 32: Extra }, or forgotten $. \sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2,[-2,1])}
document.tex: error: 32: Missing $ inserted. \sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2,[-2,1])}
document.tex: error: 32: Missing } inserted. \sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2,[-2,1])}
document.tex: error: 32: Extra }, or forgotten $. \sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2,[-2,1])}
document.tex: error: 32: Missing $ inserted. \sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2,[-2,1])}
document.tex: error: 32: Missing } inserted. \sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2,[-2,1])}

Despite the PDF being generated correctly, the error persists, which is inconvenient. I would appreciate any insights or advice on resolving this issue.

The error messages suggest a dollar sign might be missing.
A dollar sign is indeed missing right after & in this line:
s.append(r'${0}$&{1}$\\'.format(latex(xi[k]),latex(yi[k])))

The error should vanish if you add the missing $ and write:
s.append(r'${0}$&${1}$\\'.format(latex(xi[k]),latex(yi[k])))

Below a slightly refactored version, if you prefer.
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}

\begin{sagesilent}
pre_tabla = r"""\[ \displaystyle f(x) = _funcion_ \]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r|r}
  $x$ & $y$ \\
  \hline
  _valores_
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
"""
\end{sagesilent}

\begin{sagesilent}
def tabla_valores(f, xx):
    yy = [f.subs(x=x) for x in xx]
    zz = [(latex(x), latex(y)) for x, y in zip(xx, yy)]
    vv = [fr"  ${x}$ & ${y}$ \\" for x, y in zz)]
    tabla = pre_tabla.replace("_funcion_", latex(f))
    return tabla.replace("  _valores_", "\n".join(vv)
\end{sagesilent}

\sagestr{tabla_valores(x^2, [-2, 1])}

\end{document}


Thanks you too much, now it's working perfect
